# wordpress blog index is post page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, blogs

I have a custom page named 'Journal', which I use as a blog index page for my wordpress website. I've run into a rather strange problem. When I enter `<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>` or whatever in home.php, it returns the title of a post, instead of the page title 'Journal'. Is anyone familiar with this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected behavior for this page. When you set a page to be your "blog", you can't access the template tags for that page. Instead, the template tags are for the loop of the posts to be displayed on that page.

To get the title, you have to first get the id of that page, and then you can pass it to a function:

```
<?php
$page_for_blog = get_option( 'page_for_posts' );
$page_title = get_the_title( $page_for_blog );
?>
```

Now you can print the `$page_title` and you should see "Journal".

**Updated with Advanced Custom Fields**

Now that you have the Journal page's id (`$page_for_blog`), you can get your field values with:

```
$field_value = get_field( 'field_name', $page_for_blog );
```

Obviously, replace 'field_name' with whatever field you're trying to retrieve.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm afraid it's a bit more complicated than that. I'm using Advanced Custom Fields(ACF) to create some custom fields. These custom fields are filled on my journal page. Is there any way I can get their data?

Comment: Thanks, it works! However, I did need to change "get_option('page_for_posts')" by this: "get_page_by_title('page for posts')".